# Is there anything continuous within a "time-slice" of experience?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics

This is a problem with which I have genuinely been struggling for some time.

Unfortunately, it is not a "mainstream" problem, and could be misconstrued as a development of my own mind, but I would nevertheless love to hear people's thoughts.

With general certainty, we recognise today that the classical view of continuity is an approximation to the quantum mechanical view. That is, we understand that all entities in the natural world have a discrete constitution; they are "singular", they are "discrete", they are quantised - from atoms, to space, to time.

But could there, in any sense whatsoever, be considered to exist a continuum within the "time-slice" of experience itself? That is, given that our experience constitutes a mere fleeting moment in time - however small it may be - could it, *in that moment*, possess anything approaching a continuity?

For example, if one could freeze time, I daresay the corresponding experience would be a stationary fixed motion. But again, we do not *know* that! A fixed frame could inherently still possess some moving parts - who is to say?

There are not many other ways I can put this, other than to ask if there is any continuity *within the moment*.

In a more palatable way, I could ask: Is there any continuity in life whatever?

Comment: I wonder that you ask the community whether we can make up any sense in your thoughts. IMO it not the task of the reader, but the duty of the academic writer to express clearly his/her theses and questions. Please see https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help for some recommendations about Q&A on this platform.

Comment: There are only so many ways I can ask this question before I start repeating myself. Anyone who can imagine a "fixed moment of time" will be able to understand this question.

Comment: Any experiencing requires multiple neuron firings and so takes place over a much longer timescale than any quantum effects. The unit of experience is the so-called specious present that lasts much longer than a "moment" or "slice", and physical continuity/discontinuity of time at small scales is irrelevant there. For various approaches to describing how time is experienced, see [SEP, Temporal Consciousness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness-temporal).

Comment: @Conifold Many thanks for the link; I have found it refreshing to know that I'm not alone in my investigations, and that there are different views. My difficulty was in trying to reconcile the physics view, that all nature is particulate, with this sense of fluidity which pertains to my experience (and to that of others, I presume).

Comment: "all entities...have a discrete constitution" isn't quite right.  For now the best we have is quantum **field** theory; which can be interpreted as "it's all fields".  I like to think of it as *interactions* are discrete, while the fields[entities] participating in those interactions are continuous (there's still some mystery there in how do extended smooth entities come to only undergo localized, discrete interactions...)

Comment: "A fixed frame could inherently still possess some moving parts - who is to say"  in terms of Schroedinger wave mechanics, the single-time snapshot of the wavefunction of a particle at a single instant of time does in fact include all the information about its motion (i.e. momentum).

Comment: I have been having similar thoughts but I couldn't put in good words and good associations but you have put it quite well.

Answer (score 3):

Zeno's Paradoxes - The Arrow

https://iep.utm.edu/zenos-paradoxes/#SSH3aiii

> Zeno’s Arrow Paradox takes a different approach to challenging the coherence of our common sense concepts of time and motion. Think of how you would distinguish an arrow that is stationary in space from one that is flying through space, given that you look only at a snapshot (an instantaneous photo) of them. Would there be any difference?

> The Standard Solution to the Arrow Paradox requires appeal to our contemporary theory of speed from calculus. This theory defines instantaneous motion, that is, motion at an instant, without defining motion during an instant. This new treatment of motion originated with Newton and Leibniz in the sixteenth century, and it employs what is called the “at-at” theory of motion, which says motion is being at different places at different times. Motion is not some feature that reveals itself only within a moment. The modern difference between rest and motion, as opposed to the difference in antiquity, has to do with what is happening at nearby moments and—contra Zeno—has nothing to do with what is happening during a moment.

Galileo could only calculate speed using discrete values for the change in time (interval) and the change in position (displacement) where speed is displacement divided by interval. Newton describes velocity at each instant of time using a geometric relationship. The derivative is the slope of a line tangent to a curve at a point. If one assumes that acceleration is a constant or continuous varable then curves for velocity and position are also continuous. Gravity near the surface of earth is constant or we can fit it to a continuous variable for distinct locations on the surface of earth based on an experimental "fit". Humans cannot fathom all events that happen at any one instant of time our brain is sampling some events and generating our perceptions of reality.

**ADDED - 3/20/24**

Galileo is the archetype for the human scientific observer. To specify an interval of time he used water clocks or pendulum clocks. To specify displacement of a body in motion he used the concept of position based on units of length. In terms of the philosophical observer what does this mean? It means there are two continuous systems of motion the clock and the system we compare to the clock! Reality is the flow of events in the mind which is timeless without memories of aging or events that seem to be irreversible (called the arrow of time). The mind generates the concept of time as the flow of events compared to a clock (resonant system or linear irreversible system) and it invents the concepts of an instant of time and the arrow or irreversible flow of events in time. Reality is just the name for the ultimate cause of dynamic events which are timeless and eternal (never beginning or ending in absolute time) from the limited human perspective.

Comment: It's kind of funny, modern science has shown that even given an instantaneous snapshot, there is a difference between a moving and stationary arrow; so Zeno's paradox evaporates.  At the level of Schroedinger wave mechancs, the wave function of particle at a particular time does include the momentum characteristics of that particle at that time.

Comment: @Dave - I don't recall much about quantum theory from my course in Semiconductor Theory more than thirty years ago. My concept of waves is continuous functions (calculus) and my concept of particles is discrete lumps of mass that may be smaller than electrons. Is the wave function continuous or discrete math? My informal model of quantum theory is popcorn popping on the stove as a child - Jiffy-Pop popcorn. Quantum events (waves) are associated with emitter mass and detected by observer mass. We use a mix of wave math and stochastic math to integrate quantum micro events with the macroscopic.

Comment: I'm thinking of the type of stuff you'd or (or at least I did) in a 3rd year undergraduate QM course where you're thinking in terms of wavefunctions in the context of the Schroedinger equation.  There you'll have $\psi(x)$, a complex function over a spatial coordinate, that corresponds to the instantanous state of the particle it describes.  the momentum of that of that state is obtained by differentiating that wave function ($-i \frac{d \psi(x)}{dx}$.  Thus in the context of the Schroedinger formulation of QM the wavefunction at a specific time encodes both position and momentum.

Answer (score 2):

While matter is particulate, we don't yet know whether spacetime is granular in the way you assume it is, so time might be continuous. Either way, what is important is your experience of it, and that is a product of the way in which minds have evolved. When you watch a movie, the image changes in a discontinuous way every ten to twenty milliseconds (depending on the refresh rate of your TV), but your mind smooths out the jumps and gives you the impression of continuity. Time is known to be continuous over very much shorter periods, down to something like 0.0000000000000001 milliseconds (I might be  few zeros out either way), and most theories of quantised time assume time is granular down to something like 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001 milliseconds (again, give or take a few zeros), and the response time of your mind is so enormously slow by comparison, that you can take time to be continuous.

Comment: +1 Beautiful explanation

Comment: @Howwhye that is extremely kind of you!

Answer (score 2):

OP: *could there, in any sense whatsoever, be considered to exist a continuum within the "time-slice" of experience itself?*

In *Being & Time* Heidegger describes Dasein as temporal.  My impression of this is: addressing the idea from consciousness, past, present & future are fused in experience as the primary seat of activity.  We think and act in a temporal fusion and only later pick out this and that moment.  The originary temporal fusion cannot be reconstructed from the discrete moments.

Heidegger focuses more on Dasein than consciousness, so one's being is considered wholistically.  This is described in ¶72 (below), with the correspondence between past and future (memories and plans) and the processes underlying consciousness covered elsewhere.

The main point is that the *cogito* is from the start temporal and time-spanning.  The observation of energy quanta and instants of time are particulars of a different nature.

> Dasein does not exist as the sum of the momentary actualities of
> Experiences which come along successively and disappear. Nor is there
> a sort of framework which this succession gradually fills up. For how
> is such a framework to be present-at-hand, where, in each case, only
> the Experience one is having 'right now' is 'actual', and the
> boundaries of the framework—the birth which is past and the death
> which is only oncoming—lack actuality? At bottom, even in the ordinary
> way of taking the 'connectedness of life', one does not think of this
> as a framework drawn tense 'outside' of Dasein and spanning it round,
> but one rightly seeks this connectedness in Dasein itself. When,
> however, one tacitly regards this entity ontologically as something
> present-at-hand 'in time', any attempt at an ontological
> characterization of the Being 'between' birth and death will break
> down.
>
> Dasein does not fill up a track or stretch 'of life'—one which is
> somehow present-at-hand-with the phases of its momentary actualities.
> It stretches
> *itself* along in such a way that its own Being is constituted in advance as a stretching-along. The 'between' which relates to birth
> and death already lies *in the Being* of Dasein. On the other hand, it
> is by no means the case that Dasein 'is' actual in a point of time,
> and that, apart from this, it is 'surrounded' by the non-actuality of
> its birth and death. Understood existentially, birth is not and never
> is something past in the sense of something no longer present-at-hand
> ; and death is just as far from having the kind of Being of something
> still outstanding, not yet present-at-hand but coming along. Factical
> Dasein exists as born ; and, as born, it is already dying, in the
> sense of Being-towards-death. As long as Dasein factically exists,
> both the 'ends' and their 'between' *are*, and they *are* in the only
> way which is possible on the basis of Dasein's Being as *care*.

'Care' as the concernful attention to working things out.

Answer (score 2):

The time slice is directly related to phenomena (like humans). Because energy isn't quantized in an absolute sense, it is quantized in relation to everything else around. At the most fundamental level energy is continuous.

Energy is the variable property of the universal electric field (topological field under invariant volume). Its corresponding field is the magnetic field (vector field). Both fields are basic quantum fields (QFT). All the basic quantum fields (inclusive Higgs field) tessellate the mathematical volume of the universe.

We can describe time as a continuous flux of infinite small changes (like Newton's axiom about absolute time). But if we want to describe time as a noticible change we have to decide the nature of a noticable change.

Because the universal electric field is a topological field (continuous transformations of the shapes of the units of the spatial structure we have termed "universe") there are no observable/detectible "time-slices". However, if the fluent topological deformation changes direction, it is noticible. In other words, Planck's constant (*h*) only exists because we and our instruments are build up by matter (relational reality).

At every single moment the whole non-local universe is changing. Because of the invariant volume of the structure all the changes must be synchronized. So in between the start of the topological deformation of 1 quantum of energy and its maximaal amount of deformation (1 *h*) there is no change of direction by the flow of infinite small changes. But at the moment the next quantum of topological deformation starts, the build up tension will result in a change of the direction of the flow of infinite small changes.

It is not easy to describe because everything is math (geometry). However, every physics student is told that a measurement shows only a mutual relation, not an absolute property.